# Создание счетчика для имени файла

Tags: linux, bash, циклы, условия, счетчики

Заткнулся в следующем: скрипт отслеживет размер определенного файла (всегда одного) и если его размер выше статического порогового значения то создает из этого файла архив, а сам файл удаляет.
Проблема в том, что когда файл достигнет максимального значения снова, то будет создан новый архив, который перезапишет старый.
Вопрос: как сделать счетчик в имени создаваемого архива (и проверку)? Если в каталоге /1 есть файл x.tgz, то создать x1.tgz, если есть x1.tgz, то создать x2.tgz и до бесконечности.

Comment: Использовать дату в качестве расширения имени файла.

Comment: можно через logrotate, но хочется поизвращаться

Comment: С датой хорошая идея, но это чит ^^

Comment: Тогда писать скрипт, вычисляющий максимальное число в имени существующего файла архива и прибавляющий к нему 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
name=somefile
if [[ -e $name.tgz ]] ; then
    i=0
    while [[ -e $name-$i.tgz ]] ; do
        let i++
    done
    name=$name-$i
fi
touch $name.tgz
```

Comment: С этим циклом пытаюсь добиться работоспособности, но что-то ругается на fi

Comment: Все заработало. Спасибо!

Comment: Вижу один недостаток этого варианта, в случае удаления старых файлов, он будет генерировать имена файлов со старыми номерами.

Comment: Согласен, но у них будет дата создания, т.ч. определить можно.

Comment: Другой ответ лишён указанного недостатка, т.к. вычисляет номер по именам существующих файлов.

Answer (score 1):

Получите массив уже существующих файлов, отсортируйте, возьмите последний элемент, выделите из него номер, прибавьте единицу, запишите под этим именем новый файл. Соответственно, если ничего с диска не считалось, значит файл первый.

Answer (score 1):

конструкция:

```
$ base=x
$ echo $(($(ls ${base}*.tgz 2>/dev/null | sed -rn 's/.*[^0-9]([0-9]+)\.tgz/\1/p' | sort -n | tail -n 1)+1))
```

вернёт следующий номер для файлов, подпадающих под маску `x*.tgz` (и единицу в случае, если таких файлов нет или есть только `x.tgz`).

«базовое» имя указывается в переменной `base`.

---

можно сохранить этот номер в переменную `next` для дальнейшего использования:

```
base=x
next=$(($(ls ${base}*.tgz 2>/dev/null | sed -rn 's/.*[^0-9]([0-9]+)\.tgz/\1/p' | sort -n | tail -n 1)+1))
```

Comment: для полного счастья автора, данный скрипт следует дополнить `echo $next
touch $base$next.tgz`